# OS Command Injection (CWE ID 78) (1 flaw) Java code

Tags: java, security, veracode, secure-coding, commandinjection

The flaw is at Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, env) method. We have validated the input using OWASP ESAPI.

But Veracode still reports OS command injection flaw.

Old Code:

public Process exec(String[] cmd, String[] env) throws IOException {

```
  return Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, env);

}
```

New Code:

public Process exec(String[] cmd, String[] env) throws IOException {

```
  String[] newCmdArr = new String[cmd.length];

  String[] newEnvArr = new String[env.length];

  for(int i=0;i<env.length;i++)

  {

  newEnvArr[i] = CSSecurity.getValidInput(ESAPIContext.OSCommand, env[i], ESAPIType.OSCommand);               

  }       

  for ( int i = 0; i < cmd.length; i++ ) 

  {

   newCmdArr[i] = CSSecurity.getValidInput(ESAPIContext.OSCommand, cmd[i], ESAPIType.OSCommand);

  }

  return Runtime.getRuntime().exec(newCmdArr, newEnvArr);   

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `encodeForOS` ESAPI method instead:

```
import org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI;
import org.owasp.esapi.codecs.WindowsCodec;

public Process exec(String[] cmd, String[] env) throws IOException {

   String[] newCmdArr = new String[cmd.length];
   String[] newEnvArr = new String[env.length];

   for(int i=0; i<env.length; i++){
      newEnvArr[i] = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForOS(new WindowsCodec(),env[i]);
   }

   for (int i=0; i<cmd.length; i++){
      newCmdArr[i] = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForOS(new WindowsCodec(),cmd[i]);
   }
 
 return Runtime.getRuntime().exec(newCmdArr, newEnvArr);
}
```